# Setting Cloud Firestore location Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am setting a new Firebase Firestore cloud for my project. I am from India and requires South-Asia1 for location But this location is having problem like cloud functions not enabled. 
What should I do now, Should I go with my SouthAsia1 or change to nearest CloudFunctions location.
[image: Deploying a function to this location is not available]

What does it mean that  Deploying a function to this location is not yet available.
I am using firebase on Android with flutter.

> Can I have cloud Function location and Firestore location different?

Comment: Can I have my cloud Firestore location and cloud Function location different.

Answer (score 0):

If you require those functions, I'd recommend picking the closest location that offers them.

In short, the further away the location, the higher the potential latency.

Comment: **That's not true.** It's less about physical distances and much more about the **number of hops** between the servers and the clients. The best practice would be pinging to different Firebase's servers from potential client locations (I don't know where to get the server ids). It would be nice if Firebase would recommend for each country which is the preferred servers.